# Generic rank of proper pushforward of the trivial line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, coherent-sheaves, chow-groups, grothendieck-riemann-roch

Given a proper surjective morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective varieties. The proper pushforward $f_!$ is the homomorphism that sends the class of a coherent sheaf $M$ in $K_0(X)$ to $\sum_i(-1)^i[R^if_*M]$. Furthermore assume $X$ and $Y$ are abelian varieties so they have trivial tangent bundles. Let $M$ be the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$. By the application of GRR it implies that higher chern classes of $f_![\mathcal{O}_X]$ are zero. Is it also possible $f_![\mathcal{O}_X]$ to have the generic rank equal to zero? In other words is it possible for $f_![\mathcal{O}_X]$ to be zero in $K_0(Y)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$? (I am interested in the case that $f$ is the covering from a Jacobian of a curve to the arbitrary abelian variety.)

Comment: Of course, just take $f$ to be a composition $X \to \mathrm{Spec}(k) \to Y$.

Comment: Yes but in my case I meant a surjective covering between abelian varieties.

Comment: Was this assumption mentioned somewhere? If $f$ is a covering (flat finite morphism of positive degree) then the rank of $R^0f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is positive (equal to the degree of the covering) and higher direct images vanish.

Comment: This will always be the case if the fibers are  connected.

Comment: I don't think it is necessarily a flat  morphism. The morphism is a surjective homomorphism of abelian varieties.

Comment: @abx Which conclusion did you meant?

Comment: By the GRR for $f$, the rank of ${\rm R}f_*[{\cal O}_X]=f_{!}[{\cal O}_X]$ is zero if ${\rm dim}(X)>{\rm dim}(Y)$ and is the generic degree of $f$ if ${\rm dim}(X)={\rm dim}(Y)$ (or did I misunderstand something?).

Comment: @DamianRössler You are right. For some reason I didn't notice there are rank information in the chern character in GRR.

Comment: A surjective homomorphism of abelian varieties is flat.

Comment: Has your question been fully answered by Damian's comment and the comments of abx and Sasha?

Comment: @WillSawin Yes it follows from GRR as Damian explains.